# First character upper case and ignore few special characters in php

Tags: php, regex, ucfirst

I am trying to dispaly upper case text to just the first character to be upper case in a phrase. If there are any special characters they have to be ignored.

for example:

> SECTION 1: IDENTIFICATION OF THE SUBSTANCE/PREPARATION AND OF THE
>   COMPANY/UNDERTAKING

the above is my text and I want the above text to display like

> Section 1: Identification of the substance/preparation and of the
>   company/undertaking

as of now I tried **echo ucfirst(strtolower($word));**

which outputs

> Section 1: identification of the substance/preparation and of the
>   company/undertaking

How can I achieve this? 
Thank you

Comment: are responses correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `split` using `:` surrounded by optional spaced and call `ucfirst` on each split item and then join them together:

```
$out="";

foreach (preg_split('/(\h*[:.]\h*)/', strtolower($str), 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE) as $s)
   $out .= ucfirst($s)

echo "$out\n";

//=> Section 1: Identification of the substance/preparation and of the company/undertaking
```

`\h*[:.]\h*` splits on `:` or `.` with optional spaced on either side. You may add more characters here in character class that you want to split on.

Answer (score 0):

You can split in two parts:

```
$exploded = explode(': ', $phrase);
```

then ucfirst each part:

```
$exploded[0] = ucfirst($exploded[0]);
$exploded[1] = ucfirst(strtolower($exploded[1]));
```

finally you can join all:

```
echo join(': ', $exploded);
```

---

```
$phrase = 'SECTION 1: CIAO MONDO';
$exploded = explode(': ', $phrase);
$exploded[0] = ucfirst($exploded[0]);
$exploded[1] = ucfirst(strtolower($exploded[1]));
echo join(': ', $exploded); // Section 1: Ciao mondo
```